My NEXTJS project load so many module when i click a link to page
I have a small nextjs project, but every time I launch it for the first time,When i click a Link jump into my page ex:home/product/[slug] I have to wait about 12 seconds to load more than  compiling 2000 modules.
here the code down there check it thank for reading and helping me
// page.tsx (app)
'use client'
import SideBar from "@/components/SideBar/SideBar";
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header";

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
    return (
        <div className="flex ">
            <div className="lg:block hidden">
                <SideBar />
            </div>
            <div className="lg:pl-64 pl-0 flex w-full h-full min-h-screen flex-col  bg-slate-300">
                <Header />
                <div className="flex-1 text-black p-1 ">
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


this is product/[product] and it compling (2900 modules)
//app/prodcut/[slug]
"use client"
import { productSchema } from '@/components/CRUDTAB/validatorComponent'
import {AddProductField } from '@/data/ComponentData'
import {apiAddProduct } from '@/data/apiUrl'
import { columnProduct } from '@/data/listData';
import GetListComponent from '@/components/List/GetListComponent';


export default function page({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <GetListComponent
        slug={'product'}
        querySlug={'get'}
        columnData={columnProduct}
        AddDataField={AddProductField}
        dataSchema={productSchema}
        apiAddData={apiAddProduct} />
    </div>
  )


}


// GetListComponent.tsx
"use client"
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import LoadingScene from '@/components/LoadingScene'
import DataTable from '@/components/DataTable/DataTable'
import AddComponent from '@/components/CRUDTAB/AddComponent'
import getData from './getData'
type Props = {
  slug: string,
  querySlug:string,
  columnData:any,
  AddDataField:any,
  dataSchema:any,
  apiAddData:string
}

export default function GetListComponent(props: Props) {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const size = searchParams.get('size');
  const page = searchParams.get('page');
  const [data, setData] = useState<object[]>([])
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getData(props.slug,props.querySlug, size, page);
        console.log("result",result)
        setData(result);
      } catch (error) {
        setData([]);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    setLoading(false);
  }, [props.querySlug, size, page]);
  const [openAdd, setOpenAdd] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full flex flex-col'>
      {props.slug}
      <div className='m-5'>
        <button onClick={() => setOpenAdd(!openAdd)} className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
          Add Customer
        </button>
      </div>
      {loading ? <LoadingScene /> : <DataTable columns={props.columnData} rows={data} slug={props.slug} />}
      <div>
        {openAdd && <AddComponent componentData={props.AddDataField} validValueSchema={props.dataSchema} slug={'Cutomer'} setOpen={setOpenAdd} apiUrl={props.apiAddData} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


How to make fast loading

This is why people use bundlers like Webpack or Vite or whatever, to do all the work of resolving imports and create a much more efficient packaging of the scripts.

So first of all. Do you need all this "use client" tags? If you query data in next usually you should do it on server.
Second for your issue: maybe your DataTable is rendering too many times too many components?
